# Find characters of this word in another word Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, compare, character

I am making a guessing word game. So if I was given word `lime-tree`. Then I want to check for the possible words within that word. If I guessed `lime`,  `tree`, `time`, `reel` or guess even not a real word etc. then they are all `true`, since they are made from this word. How do I check if the word guessed is within this word?

#### Edited

I forgot to mention that the letters cannot be more than specified in the given word.

Comment: Does it have to use a dictionary?

Comment: is that `-` is also included in gues???

Comment: no it doesnt need a dictionary and doesnt have to include - i putted in because the given word is not a word without -.

Comment: @user3650234 check the code is that you wanted

Comment: @user3650234, can you be more clear on whether the letter in word can be reused? like `eeeeee` still OK with given word `lime-tree`? My answer will be `Not in given_word`, whereas other answer may return `True`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the letters cannot be more than specified in the given word. Thanks for the quick post guys i will try them out tomorrow morning.

Comment: @user3650234, great. My understanding is correct and I think my answer delivers what you're asking for

Comment: Thanks guys both worked perfectly:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may make use of `Counter`, to count all letters in given word, and subtract the letters from the word to be checked, something like this:

```
from collections import Counter


def check_in_given_word(given_word, to_check):
    given_word_counter = Counter(given_word)
    word_counter = Counter(to_check)
    given_word_counter.subtract(word_counter)
    #if any -ve letter count is found, it is not in given_word
    if any([c < 0 for c in given_word_counter.values()]):
        # do whatever you want, or return False
        print "{} is NOT in {}".format(to_check, given_word)
    else:
        print "{} is in {}".format(to_check, given_word)
    # print the counter for your info
    print given_word_counter
```

Sample usage:

```
check_in_given_word('lime-tree', 'tree')
tree is in lime-tree
Counter({'e': 1, 'i': 1, 'm': 1, '-': 1, 'l': 1, 'r': 0, 't': 0})

check_in_given_word('lime-tree', 'reel')
reel is in lime-tree
Counter({'e': 1, 'i': 1, 'm': 1, '-': 1, 't': 1, 'l': 0, 'r': 0})

check_in_given_word('lime-tree', 'hello')
hello is NOT in lime-tree
Counter({'e': 2, 'i': 1, 'm': 1, '-': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1, 'l': -1, 'o': -1, 'h': -1})

check_in_given_word('lime-tree', 'reeeeel')
reeeeel is NOT in lime-tree
Counter({'i': 1, 'm': 1, '-': 1, 't': 1, 'l': 0, 'r': 0, 'e': -2})
```

As you can see, all letters should be +ve values. If any negative values is found, the word to check is not in your given word.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple one
I have use `count`, if in new_word count is more for a letter it will return wrong . or at last return Correct.

```
>>> def word_check(original,new_word):
...     for x in new_word:
...         if new_word.count(x) > original.count(x):
...             return "Wrong"
...     return "Correct"
... 
>>> word_check('lime-tree','trel')
'Correct'
>>> word_check('lime-tree','treeel')
'Correct'
>>> word_check('lime-tree','treeeel')
'Wrong'
>>> word_check('lime-tree','mile')
'Correct'
>>> word_check('lime-tree','miilet')
'Wrong'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is also not correct, consider this: `word_check('lime-tree', 'eeeeeee')`, will return `Correct` which is incorrect

Comment: if one want for length greater than one can do validation, using len `function`

Comment: um... good point, I think OP isn't clear about if letter can be reused, I don't think so cause otherwise the given word can just be 'lim-tre'

Comment: brilliant! I think your approach is cleaner than mine! Although I use similar logic in my created game because I need the counter part. Great stuff man :)